# Swig-generated Constants in Python

Tags: python, swig

I'm using SWIG to create a Python interface to my C++ class library.

**I can't work out how to utilise the constants created by SWIG in Python**.  I can't even print their value.

For example, both these print statements in Python fail silently...

```
print CONST1
print rep (CONST1)
```

In **C++**, I have this

```
#define CONST1 0x20000
const int CONST2 = 0x20000; // No different to #define in SWIG-generated code.
```

If I look at the **Python module** created by SWIG it has something like this...

```
CONST1 = _theCPPlibrary.CONST1
```

Additionally, I tried using the SWIG %constant directive as an experiment (I don't really want to use this if I can avoid it, as it involves duplicating my constants in the SWIG input file).  The %constant directive also gives the same results.

I'm a C++ programmer, and a noob in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After build, you will get a python source file: theCPPlibrary.py, and a pyd file: _theCPPlibrary.pyd. You must import the python module first:

```
import theCPPlibrary
```

CONST1 is defined by #define, it can be access by:

```
print theCPPlibrary.CONST1
```

CONST2 is defined by const, is't a global variable, access it by:

```
print theCPPlibrary.cvar.CONST2
```

Comment: I didn't prefix it with the library name.  Thanks!